Baking Hi to low poly with existing normal map
Is there a way to bake from Hi to low poly when the hi poly model already has a normal map?  I'm baking from a 300k model to a decimated 3k mesh.  The 300k mesh already has an existing normal map. So, it was probably baked once already, from an even higher poly mesh.
When baking - the hi poly geometry bakes correctly into the low-poly normal map, but the low-poly normal map does not include any of the texture data from the hi-poly normal map.

I would look into combining normal maps(harder than it seems).

@MartynasŽiemys that would only work if both normals were baked from the same object UVs.
